# Pull value of a particular node using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xpath

I am facing an issue to pull value from a particular node in XML using XPath. What I'm trying to do is to get a value from a node based on a value in other node. So the value in the other node is a condition when I'm querying an XML.

Here's my XPath code in C#:

I can pull the value using the position of the node.

```
String webURL3;
            WebRequest YRCRateQuote;
            WebResponse resp3;
            Stream respStream3;
            XmlDocument rateQuote3 = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode freightChargeSP1;
            XmlNode freightChargeSP2;
            XmlNode freightChargeSP3;
            XmlNode freightChargeSP4;
            XmlNode freightChargeSP5;
            XmlNode freightChargeSP6;
            XmlNode freightChargeSP7;
            XmlNode serviceDaysSP;


            //build web request
            webURL3 = String.Format(web service string);

            //create web request
            YRCRateQuote = WebRequest.Create(webURL3);

            //make web service call
            resp3 = YRCRateQuote.GetResponse();

            //read response 
            respStream3 = resp3.GetResponseStream();
            rateQuote3.Load(respStream3);

            //Use Name Space
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(rateQuote3.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("rq", "http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1");

//This works get the value of the first TOTAL_COST node
freightChargeSP2 = rateQuote3.SelectSingleNode("//rq:SERVICEUPGRADES[1]//rq:TOTAL_COST", nsmgr);

//But this one gives me null if I want to pull the value depending upon value in the other node
freightChargeSP1 = rateQuote3.SelectSingleNode("//rq:SERVICEUPGRADES[SERVICE_TYPE='regional delivery']//rq:TOTAL_COST", nsmgr);

//I also tried doing this
freightChargeSP1 = rateQuote3.SelectSingleNode("//rq:SERVICEUPGRADES//rq:TOTAL_COST[SERVICE_TYPE='regional delivery']", nsmgr);
```

Changing // to / didn't help it either.

Here's the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<RateQuoteResponse xmlns="http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1">
  <STATUS>
    <CODE>0</CODE>
    <VIEW>SECURED</VIEW>
    <VERSION>
      <CURRENT>V2X1</CURRENT>
      <CURRENT_RELEASE_DATE>02/06/2010</CURRENT_RELEASE_DATE>
      <LATEST>V2X1</LATEST><LATEST_RELEASE_DATE>02/06/2010</LATEST_RELEASE_DATE>
    </VERSION></STATUS>
  <RateQuote>
    <ORIGIN>
      <NAME>INDIANAPOLIS</NAME>
      <CARRIER>USF Holland, Inc</CARRIER>
      <ADDRESS>2530 S TIBBS AVE</ADDRESS>
      <CITY>INDIANAPOLIS</CITY>
      <STATE>IN</STATE>
      <ZIP>46241</ZIP>
      <PHONE>3172277627</PHONE>
      <PHONE_TOLLFREE>8006274831</PHONE_TOLLFREE>
      <FAX>3172277629</FAX>
    </ORIGIN>
    <DESTINATION>
      <NAME>INDIANAPOLIS</NAME>
      <CARRIER>USF Holland, Inc</CARRIER>
      <ADDRESS>2530 S TIBBS AVE</ADDRESS>
      <CITY>INDIANAPOLIS</CITY>
      <STATE>IN</STATE>
      <ZIP>46241</ZIP>
      <PHONE>3172277627</PHONE>
      <PHONE_TOLLFREE>8006274831</PHONE_TOLLFREE>
      <FAX>3172277629</FAX>
    </DESTINATION>
    <ORIGIN_ZIP>46202</ORIGIN_ZIP>
    <DESTINATION_ZIP>46204</DESTINATION_ZIP>
    <TOTAL_COST>117.02</TOTAL_COST>
    <DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>85.0</DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>
    <DISCOUNTAMOUNT>512.04</DISCOUNTAMOUNT>
    <SERVICEDAYS>1</SERVICEDAYS>
    <INDUSTRYDAYS>1.5</INDUSTRYDAYS>
    <CLASSWEIGHT>
      <CLASS>60</CLASS>
      <ASCLASS>60</ASCLASS>
      <WEIGHT>1500</WEIGHT>
      <CHARGES>602.4</CHARGES>
    </CLASSWEIGHT>
    <ADDIONALCHARGES>
      <RATE>Fuel Surcharge</RATE>
      <CHARGES>26.66</CHARGES>
      <DESCRIPTION>FSC29.50% ON DIESEL OF 386.7</DESCRIPTION>
    </ADDIONALCHARGES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>Please Call Customer Service for Available Days and Times</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>Single-hour Window</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed window</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>267.02</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>Please Call Customer Service for Available Days and Times</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>Multi-hour Window</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed window</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>267.02</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>Please Call Customer Service for Available Days and Times</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>Single or Multi Day Window</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed window</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>152.02</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDATE>07/17/2013</DELIVERYDATE>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>1</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>before 9:00 AM</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed delivery</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>217.02</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDATE>07/17/2013</DELIVERYDATE>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>1</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>before 12:00 PM (noon)</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed delivery</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>182.02</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDATE>07/17/2013</DELIVERYDATE>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>1</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>before 3:30 PM</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed delivery</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>152.02</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDATE>07/17/2013</DELIVERYDATE>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>1</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>regional delivery</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>117.02</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
  </RateQuote>
</RateQuoteResponse>
```

Comment: ...but what are you actually trying to do (in plain English)?

Comment: I am trying to get a value in a node depending upon value in other node..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerably easier with LinqToXml because the explicit cast operators make all your type conversions easy:

```
XNamespace ns="http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //or whatever
var costNode = doc
    .Root
    .Descendants(ns + "SERVICEUPGRADES")
    .Single(e => (string)e.Element(ns + "SERVICE_TYPE") == "regional delivery")
    .Element(ns + "TOTAL_COST");
var cost = (decimal)costNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the namespace also to SERVICE_TYPE:

```
"//rq:SERVICEUPGRADES[rq:SERVICE_TYPE='regional delivery']//rq:TOTAL_COST"
```